# How does C# write bitmap data. is it bottom up or top down?

Tags: c#, bitmap

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) :

> The pixel array is a block of 32-bit DWORDs, that describes the image
>   pixel by pixel. Normally pixels are stored "upside-down" with respect
>   to normal image raster scan order, starting in the lower left corner,
>   going from left to right, and then row by row from the bottom to the
>   top of the image.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format)  Uncompressed Windows bitmaps also can be stored
>   from the top to bottom, when the Image Height value is negative.

So, when I use this code:

```
b.Save(outputFilename, ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

How does C# actually save it ? Can I tell C# to save it with height value negative and write it in top down manner ?

Comment: Man, I hate being one of "those people," but I'll ask anyway.. Why?

Comment: i am doing bitmap image manipulation, somebody please help me

Comment: so you want to flip image? `b.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);`

Comment: hey no. Thats not what i want to do. Iam interested in determining how C# saves the bitmap data.

Comment: Copy half of it and put rest to 0, and see which half is black! :D

Comment: C# doesn't save anything. Your question should be how does the .Net framework do it.

Comment: @RuneGrimstad the .NET framework doesn't do it either! It just passes the work to GDI+

Comment: Overly pedantic answers are overly pedantic. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `ImageCodecInfo` for the BMP format does not seem to support any `EncoderParameters`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882579.aspx) for more details on that. So there seems to be no way to specify how it should be stored. As to find out how it *is* stored, just try it. Make an image that's black in the upper half and white in the lower half and view it in a hex editor.

I bet it's 'upside-down' since it's the default.

Answer (score 0):

No, the height property must be greater than 0.

Comment: then why have mentioned about a negative height value in that article ?

Comment: @user581734 "then why have mentioned about a negative height value in that article ?" Again, because your Wiki link is about the BMP format, and your question is about the .Net implementation.

Comment: The height property has nothing to do with how the data is stored on disk.

Comment: @noah1989 But it has everything to do with the question.

Comment: @rfmodulator but only after the edit which I had overlooked -.-

Comment: @rfmodulator which is when I read the question and started researching.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5999/discussion-between-noah1989-and-rfmodulator)

Comment: @noah1989 Then you should be able to provide a better answer than mine, with an hour of research.