# Image flipping when convert image to base64

Tags: wpf, base64, bitmapimage, rectangles, imagebrush

I have a rectangle and fill it with a image

```
 <Rectangle Height="95" Fill="{Binding Path=Image,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource ConvertBase64toImage}}" Stroke="{x:Null}" x:Name="EditPhotoRectangel">
       <Rectangle.BitmapEffect>
           <DropShadowBitmapEffect ShadowDepth="7" Softness="0.75"/>
       </Rectangle.BitmapEffect>
 </Rectangle>
```

Image is a base64 string that i set image for it.

```
 private string ImageToBase64(System.Drawing.Image image, ImageFormat format)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Convert Image to byte[]
            image.Save(ms, format);
            byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

            // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            return base64String;
        }
    }
```

and use a converter for convert Base64 to imagebrush for fill rectangle .

```
 ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
 BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
 // convert base64string to byte[].
 byte[] binaryData = System.Convert.FromBase64String((string)value);
 bitmap.BeginInit();
 // Initializes a new non-resizable instance of the MemoryStream class based on the binaryData array.
 bitmap.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(binaryData);
 bitmap.EndInit();
 //set bitmapimage for brush imagesource 
 brush.ImageSource = bitmap;
 return brush;
```

My problem is: when I selected a image for this `Rectangle` fill with myimage flipping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use

```
 FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
```

it is work for me :)

Answer (score 2):

This is just a wild guess...need to write a sample to confirm...

I notice you are using `System.Drawing.Image` to encode the source bitmap binary data and `System.Windows.Media.BitmapImage` for the deserialization of the binary data.

There must be some difference in support between the encoders/decoders in the GDI+ (WinForms) world, and WPF (DirectX)....in particular you might have issues if you are using `ImageFormat.MemoryBmp`, or `myimage.RawFormat` (i.e. the property exposed on an `Image`).

It just so happens that DIBs (device independent bitmaps) usually have their scanlines stored in a bottom to top fashion i.e. upside down (negative stride).

So it could be to do with the way you created/initialized the `System.Drawing.Bitmap` that is the source of this whole process....maybe you used `CopyPixels`...which pointed to data where the pixels where in bottom to top arrangement or vice versa.

Have you tried doing a `.Save` to a physical BMP or JPEG file on that incoming `Bitmap` to see if it's the right way around (you can even do that in the debugger).

If you can't track down the cause of this conversion fiasco, then some possible solutions are:

- do the necessary transform to flip your image back to the appropriate way
  or
- use a different `ImageFormat`/create the incoming `Bitmap` in a different way
  or
- when you deserialize the base64 data back into a bitmap use the `System.Drawing.Image` class again (so you used the same type of class on both ends of the serialization process), but then convert that object into a `BitmapImage` object.

If you can provide more detail on how you are creating the incoming `System.Drawing.Bitmap` that would help i.e. are you loading it from a file (which format is it?), or you created one then drew onto it via a `Graphics` context, or you used CopyPixels and copied the raw pixel data from somewhere (e.g. from out of a DIB which usually stores the scan lines bottom to top).

Some informational links:

- [How does C# write bitmap data. is it bottom up or top down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572260/how-does-c-sharp-write-bitmap-data-is-it-bottom-up-or-top-down)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd407212(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot, i use   >  System.Drawing.Image img=System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(openfile.FileName);     for get image.

Comment: What ImageFormat do you use to save your image?